# Google Data Studio Connector: 'field' was used more than once in the schema. Schema field ids must be unique

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I'm writing a Google Data Studio connector which connects to an external API to retrieve data. Even though this field is only created once in the `getFields(request)` method, I'm getting an error saying that it's been used more than once.

`getSchema(request)`:

```
function getSchema(request) {
  return { schema: this._getFields(request).build() };
}
```

`getFields(request)`:

```
function getFields(request) {
  var fields = cc.getFields();
  var types = cc.getTypes();
  var aggregations = cc.aggregationType;

  fields.newMetric()
    .setId('date')
    .setName('Date')
    .setType(types.YEAR_MONTH_DAY);

  return fields;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

During the data retrieval process, each time you call `getFields(request)`, it will append those fields to the connector's existing set of fields. To avoid this duplication, you can't call this function more than once each time you refresh your data.

To get around this, call `getSchema(request)` once to retrieve the connector's schema, and then pass its `schema` object to whichever functions need access to its fields:

```
function getData(request) {
  var allFields = getSchema(request).schema;  // gets the connector's schema
  var requestedFields = getRequestedFields(request, allFields);  // gets the requested fields from the schema
  var data = fetchFromAPI(request, requestedFields);  // gets API data based on the requested fields

  // returns the data to GDS in the JSON format that it requires.
  return {
    schema: requestedFields,
    rows: data
  }
}
```

As you can see, `getSchema(request)` is only called once during the entire data retrieval process, and so no duplication has occurred.